# How to generate a CRL (certificate revocation list) file

Tags: java, certificate, cer

I'm using self-signed certificates for testing, how can I generate certificate revocation list to test cert verification? Has keytool in JDK provided such functionalities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSL http://www.openssl.org/

The CA (included) is excellent for testing simple PKIs. Perhaps a little bit daunting at first, but there is plenty of info around.

For CRLs, the out of the box setup should do the trick for you:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ca.html#CRL-OPTIONS

All the best.

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation from above.
CRL could be created by the following commands.
openssl ca -revoke test.pem -config my.cnf
openssl ca -gencrl -out test.crl -config my.cnf