# How to generate a CRL (certificate revocation list) in java

Tags: java, list, certificate

I'm wokrking on a PKI project and i want to generate a list of revoked certificates.
How can accomplish this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean 'generate'? or perhaps 'acquire'?

Comment: I mean creating a .crl file containing revoked certificates whenever it is revoked by the CA.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a vanilla Java solution to do this. Most people would probably generate a CRL using the `openssl` command-line tool. However, it seems that the Bouncy Castle library provides support for the generation of CRLs in Java.

**References:**

- [How to generate a CRL (certificate revocation list) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753671/how-to-generate-a-crl-certificate-revocation-list-file)
- [Bouncy Castle CRL generation](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Certificate+Revocation+Lists)