# How to generate CRL certificate for PFX cert Type using openssl?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Well i have certificate and keyfile of type pfx (servercert.pfx, serverkey.pfx) Can anybody help me to get a openssl cmd to generate CRL certificate for these cert ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a CRL (certificate revocation list) file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753671/how-to-generate-a-crl-certificate-revocation-list-file)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).